# Buggy makeappx or docs?

Tags: desktop-bridge

`makeappx` says my manifest is incorrect after I changed it according to docs.

Docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-extensions#open

Change:

```
<uap:Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
    <uap3:FileTypeAssociation Name="torrents" UseUrl="true" Parameters="%1">
      <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
        <uap:FileType>.torrent</uap:FileType>
      </uap:SupportedFileTypes> 
    </uap3:FileTypeAssociation>
</uap:Extension>
```

Error it generates:

```
MakeAppx : error: Error info: error C00CE015: App manifest validation error: The app manifest must be valid as per schema: Line 44, Column 55, Reason: The attribute 'UseUrl' on the element '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/3}FileTypeAssociation' is not defined in the DTD/Schema.

MakeAppx : error: Package creation failed.

MakeAppx : error: 0x80080204 - The specified package format is not valid: The package manifest is not valid.
```

Comment: Can you try adding the http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/desktop/windows10/2 namespace? According to this schema reference doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-uap-filetypeassociation, it looks like the "desktop2" prefix is being used which implies the requirement of that namespace. If that works, then the doc will have to be updated to reflect that requirement.

Comment: It's already there (initially added by DAC).